# Tools for testing a Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm currently using Gatling & a home grown solution, but I was wondering if Kafka offer anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Kafka has both `kafka-{producer,consumer}-perf-test.sh` included